# Windows 8 GridView - show two items per time

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I need to implement a sort of book using the GridView Control.
In particular I'm looking for a way to display only 2 items per time and still to be able to scroll the whole list using scrollbars.

Comment: Please try to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but I'm assuming you are asking how to ask 2 rows or columns of blocks to your application. 
Have a look at the default new Metro app template. It's hub page has a multi-line gridview. The key is to use a WrapGrid, or VariableSizedWrapGrid to display your items. In the example, a gridview is used, but then the wrapgrid is used as the item template (used for each group of items).

Comment: Hi, I mean I want to display and scroll 2 items per time, like a sort of book. Any thoughts

Comment: I'd consider using a FlipView for that, populating each page with 2 items at a time.

Comment: ok, but how can I tell to FlipView to display 2 items at a time?

Comment: You can create a new collection containing grouping items, with 2 items in each grouping. Then you bind your flipview to the grouped list, and use a template to display the 2 items in the grouping.

Comment: Link to an example of how to use the FlipView: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/FlipView-Control-f9d9a99c